# Meaning of "excited much", "stalker much"

Tags: meaning, idioms, adverbs, contemporary-english

What does 'excited much' or 'stalker much' mean exactly, and which context are they used in? I don't get the usage of *much* after a noun or adjective. I often see this construction in comments, for example.

Comment: You'll probably need to include a full sentence example or two to convey the context of your question.

Comment: I think these are both totally non-grammatical usages from non-native speakers. My guess is they're often generated by Chinese/Japanese speakers who just assume **much** is a "general-purpose intensifier". So *excited much* is a non-standard attempt to convey *very excited*, and *stalker much* is an even more non-standard attempt to convey *person who very much displays the qualities of being a stalker*. Anyway, they're not remotely "standard English", so I think the question is Too Localised for ELU (but might be relevant to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: I doubt it. Unless I have not heard correctly, Kari Byron pronounced it in the latest Mythbusters episode (racing cars myths)  at 7:50 during the presentation of their myth. I

Comment: @FumbleFingers - this is from young native speakers. It isn't standard English, but it is common slang.

Comment: @Rory: It's still non-standard and Too Localised say far as I'm concerned. I find it hard to believe that many young speakers find themselves needing to ask something like *"Do you often behave like a stalker?"* in just two words like that.

Comment: I'm not meaning the stalker bit. Just the use of 'much' after pretty much anything:-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [blame Joss Whedon](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BuffySpeak) (warning: black hole, ahem, sorry, TVTropes link)

Comment: The contexts I've heard *X much?* in general seem disparate to me: I've seen *Jealous much?* used in a taunting way that means "Shouldn't you be feeling jealous (of me) right now?" AND in a moderating way that means "Don't you think you're acting a bit too jealous?" Without inflection or other contextual cues, I don't think I can say with certainty what the speaker means.

Comment: From personal experience, this usage has been around since at least the mid-90's. As @dingo_dan points out, it should generally be punctuated with a question mark.

Comment: My problem with the question is that as familiar as I am with "(X) much?", the OP's examples don't really fit the model. For example, I can understand "stalk much?" But not "stalker much?" and "get excited much?" but not "excited much?" which is why I asked for full sentence examples. I think this question should be better documented and retagged for idiom usage.

Comment: @Martha: I've already spent more time on TVTropes than doctors would advise for lifetime exposure. Now I'm always careful to lay a trail of cookie crumbs between my bed and the keyboard before I venture in there!

Comment: @KristinaLopez The Language Log article I cited in my answer talks about how people use “X much?” even in cases where X doesn't readily fit the logic of a full question.

Comment: @RoryAlsop This is totally Generation X slang! I appreciate you saying that we're “young speakers,” although I would expect actual young people to say something more like “You mad bro?” ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mark Liberman of Language Log discusses the [“X much?”](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2836) idiom with a recent entry from OED (some emphasis mine, some examples omitted):

> *colloq.* (orig. *U.S.,* freq. *ironic*). With a preceding adjective, infinitive verb, or noun phrase, forming an elliptical comment or question. The use was popularized by the film *Buffy, the Vampire Slayer* and the television series derived from it.
>   **1988** D. Waters ***Heathers*** (film script) 86 *Heather Duke.* It was J.D.'s idea! He made out the signature sheet and everything. Now will you sign it. *Veronica. (queasy)* No. *Heather Duke.* **Jealous much?**
>   **1992** J. Whedon ***Buffy the Vampire Slayer*** (film script) 25 Pike and Benny have entered the diner, quite drunk.‥ *Kimberly (to the other girls)* **Smell of booze much.**
>   **1998** M. Burgess & R. Green *Isabella* in ***Sopranos*** (television shooting script) 1st Ser. 1 42 *Anthony Jr.* Probably I can't go to that dance now either. *Meadow.* God, **self-involved much?**

Liberman notes that the idiom uses *much* in novel ways: “Jealous much?” insinuates that the target is quite jealous, whereas the conventional “Are you jealous much?” would inquire as to frequency, not intensity. He also notes how people use “X much?” even for words that don't easily expand to a full question: “Ad hominem much?” or “Martyr much?”

In my experience, the idiom ranges from whimsical to critical to sarcastic. Sometimes it's a teasing accusation, and sometimes it's even a boastful suggestion that the target *should* be “jealous much.” A similar idiom, [“You mad bro?”](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=you%20mad%20bro?) has gained currency in recent years for cases where the target is angry.

Comment: Has someone ever _heard_ "You mad bro" ?

Comment: @Antoine I certainly have! My 19-year-old daughter says it occasionally, for one.

Comment: @Antoine That should actually be "You mad, bro?" with comma=pause.

Comment: @Merk While we'd normally use a pause/comma when addressing someone like that, when I've heard “you mad bro” spoken it has unconventional intonation. In fact, it often lacks the intonation of a question, so it might best be transcribed without comma **or** question mark.

Answer (score 13):

I think you are referring to a construction in which a characterization is presented in one word followed by the word much, read as a rhetorical question and intended as a criticism. It is not intended or imagined to be grammatically correct.

"Excited much?" would be "Do you get (this) excited often?" and is intended to paint the subject's enthusiasm as unwarranted and to suggest that it reflects on or represents the subject's general character.

"Stalker much?" is an attempt to portray behavior as stalker-like and would be grammatically written "Do you often behave like a stalker?"

Comment: This seems to be quite commonly spoken amongst young teens (certainly in the UK I have heard it from some of my children's classmates)

Comment: +1 Excellent answer (although I have also seen this idiom used whimsically and boastfully, not just critically). I added my own answer mainly to provide references and historical context, not because I disagree with you.

Comment: Not sure why you say it's "found online," this reminds me more of something a teenage girl would say.

Comment: It's a matter of exposure - I had only seen it online and only realized it was more than an internet meme by reading other comments. I've edited out those words, with a note.

Comment: In the usage I've seen, this *does not* refer to frequency ("do you get excited much/often") and not is it a real question; more like a rhetorical question. It is more like "are you very ('much') excited?", but as I say, asked as a rhetorical question to imply that you *are* very excited, especially when perhaps you wouldn't be expected to be.

Comment: @CaesarsGrunt: The tone of your comment is of disagreement, but the substance is more or less in agreement with the answer.

Comment: @GetzelR, no, I do not agree with the answer; sorry if I wasn't clear. You say that "Exited much?" means "Do you get excited often?", I say that it means "You are excited [when you shouldn't be/would not be expected to be]".

Comment: @caesarsgrunt You were clear. We are in agreement that the question is rhetorical and the intent is to suggest the behavior is unwarranted or inappropriate, not necessarily frequent.

To the question of how the words convey that intent I respond that the word much refers to frequency and is intended to treat the underlying criticism as settled and focus the question on frequency: "You are a stalker. Do you do that much?" The criticism is not the frequency - we are in agreement. 

Even if you disagree with that aspect of it, it seems a minor element.

Comment: We agree about the meaning, yes, but seemingly not the expansion to grammatically correct English. "Do you get excited often?" refers to the frequency with which the person gets excited, but "Excited much?" does not refer to that frequency, simply to the fact that the person is unreasonably excited at this moment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8972/discussion-between-getzelr-and-caesarsgrunt)

Comment: @caesarsgrunt is correct. It is not used to mean "Do you <something> often?" but rather "Are you really so very <something>?" The force of the *much* is the heart of what the phrase means, so not I think "a minor element."

Answer (score 0):

I remember this first appearing (in the 80's) in the form of "walk much?" if someone trips or stumbles.  Like "Are you new to this walking thing?" Or varieties like "eat much?" if someone drops food out of their mouth, "talk much?" if someone trips over their words, etc.

It later evolved into other uses that seemed a bit more affected.